# size of images in bash

Tags: image, bash

I have a folder containing images of JPEG format , what I would like to do is to read the size of each image and save it in 2 variables using bash.
Height
Width

The thing is when  I use this code

```
for dir in /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/OpenCV/positive/*; do
 OUTPUT="$(identify "$dir"/*.{jpg,png,jpeg)}" 

my_val1=$(echo $a3  | awk -F'x' '{print $1}')
my_val2=$(echo $a3  | awk -F'x' '{print $2}')
```

I don't loop over all the images in the folder !

Comment: `)}` should be `})`. What's `$a3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

cd  /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/OpenCV/positive

for f in *.png *.jpg *.jpeg; do
   read w h < <(convert "$f" -format "%w %h" info:)
   echo $f, $w, $h
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
a.png, 770, 1170
b.png, 770, 1170
fred.png, 1024, 1024
image.jpg, 100, 100
```

Or, if you don't really need them in variables, you can do:

```
convert /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/OpenCV/positive/*.{jpg,png,jpeg} -format "%f %w %h\n" info:
```